# Get Html Dom of custom control dll in ASP.NET web form to use it in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-controls, html-helper

I have a dll file that included a custom control, I use it in ASP.NET web form as following:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="JQControls" Namespace="JQControls" TagPrefix="custom" %>

<custom:JQLoader runat="server" />
<custom:JQDatePicker Regional="fa" runat="server" />
```

So I need to use it in MVC, and this is my plan: 1-define an Html Helper: Load ASP.NET Web Page use Firebug to get rendered Html and use this html in MVC Html helper, but that not worked. 2-Also I try ASPX Partial view and entered the exact above codes.

**EDIT**
This custom control is a textbox that when click it a custome datepicker appear.

The first approach just have a textbox without any datepicker, but second approach rise an exception before the page appear:

```
Error executing child request for handler 
'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'.

Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Does any one have any idea about how use this dll in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

If the control depends on ViewState, then it won't be possible to use it directly in an MVC page.  You could load an asp.net webforms page in an iframe or similar, but you will have to deal with the mismatch of the two technologies.

I can't tell from your question much else, because your question is not coherent enough.  The phrase "The first approach not worked properly without any error" is just confusing as to what you mean.

EDIT:

If you just want to use a datepicker, there are plenty of examples of how to do that easily in MVC and jquery ui.  It's a few lines of code.  Why do you insist on using this custom dll?

Comment: Actually jquary ui does not support Persian(Jalali) Calendar, that is just a month name translation in Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @dotNetist - There are other jquery datepickers that support other calendars.  For example: http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html